# sum of two columns select query in php mysql

Tags: sql-server

I want to output `0` not `NULL`

[Here Is Link For Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8d8f/20/0)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [pid] int, [cid] int, [NetAmount] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [pid], [cid],[NetAmount])
VALUES
    (1, 1,2, 20),
    (1, 1,2, 20),
    (1, 1,2, 20),
    (1, 1,2, 20),
    (1, 1,2, 20),
    (1, 1,2, 20);


select 
   ( select sum(NetAmount) 
    from Table1 
    where pid = '1') - 

    ( select sum(NetAmount) 
    from Table1 
    where cid = '1')
```

Comment: Do you use MySQL or SQL Server? Because tag is MySQL but Fiddle is SQL  Server. In MySQL you can use the `IFNULL()` function

Comment: Not able to understand your output,can you please brief me more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applying `null` to any arithmetic operation will result in a `null`. You can work around this by using the `coalesce` function:

```
select 
   ( select coalesce(sum(NetAmount), 0) 
    from Table1 
    where pid = '1') - 

    ( select coalesce(sum(NetAmount), 0) 
    from Table1 
    where cid = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISNULL()` function:

```
select ( select ISNULL(sum(NetAmount) ,0)
         from Table1 
         where pid = '1') -                 
       ( select ISNULL(sum(NetAmount),0)
         from Table1 
         where cid = '1')
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
       ( select isnull(sum(NetAmount),0)
        from Table1 
        where pid = '1') - 

        ( select isnull(sum(NetAmount),0) 
        from Table1 
        where cid = '1')
```